# Create tile map in Cocos2D-X by not using TMX file

Tags: cocos2d-x

I used to make a tile base game in Windows with my own tile map file, but it is a static tile map. I use an 2D array to store of my tile map. Now I want to make game in smartphone by using Cocos2D-X, and I want to make a random tile map, so I guess using TMX file is not appropriate in this case. I tried to search about making a tile map with Cocos2D-X but there is only a tutorial with TMX file.

Can you give me an idea about this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate the tmx file before you open the level.  The format is open:

https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format

That way you can take advantage of all the good things Cocos2D can do for you, and still have a random map.

Comment: Ah, I see, so I don't have to create new tile map format. Just use the TMX file and write the algorithm for generate the map.